# Plsql select * from record is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one record and I store into some values.

```
SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO record from s;
```

Is it possible to

```
SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO ids FROM record
```

I get record not table or view. Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bulk collection is not a table. It's more like an array. You access elements as `record(index)`

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are `record` and `ids` defined?  And what version of Oracle are you on?

At least since 18c, assuming `record` is defined either in SQL or in a package specification, you can use it in subsequent queries.

```
create table foo( foo_id integer, foo_val varchar2(10));

insert into foo values( 1, 'a' );
insert into foo values( 2, 'b' );

create or replace package pkg_foo
as
  type foo_nt is table of foo%rowtype;
end;
/

declare
--  type foo_nt is table of foo%rowtype;
  type id_nt is table of number;
  l_foos pkg_foo.foo_nt;
  l_ids  id_nt;
begin
  select *
    bulk collect into l_foos
    from foo;
    
  select foo_id
    bulk collect into l_ids
    from table(l_foos);
end;
/
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3fd1e84ff4e1f62241d10455166f568) showing this code working.

Note that if you uncomment the line that declares the `foo_nt` in the declarations of the anonymous block, the code will not work correctly-- you need the collection definition to be separate.